# Construct 2 app won't install (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk, construct-2

I made an app in Construct 2 and simulated it in XDK. It all worked well.

I even launched it on my phone with XDK and it worked perfect!

Then I downloaded it and wanted to install it on my phone, where I can tap "install" all day long but nothing happens. I made sure that it's allowed to install apps from unknown sources but it didn't help.

I just don't get what the problem is. I hope to get some help here.

Comment: Are you building with "optimize for Crosswalk"? If so, please confirm that you are installing the correct architecture, ARM or x86. One will work and one will not.

Comment: Tried both types of apk on my phone. None of them worked.

Comment: I've seen this happen because a previous version was installed, and there was some sort of a strange collision. A "previous version" means any other app with the same App ID (aka package ID). That means, if you've got another app on your phone with the same App ID (e.g. xdk.template.blank) they will collide; as far as Android is concerned they are the same app. Uninstall any previous copy of the app or, if there is an app that has the same App ID, uninstall it. Then try installing your new app.